# ClassNotFoundException when dynamically calling a Class with forName()

Tags: java, eclipse, class, dynamic

I am trying to call a particular Class dynamically, specifically `MyClass0`, in eclipse.

Fully Qualified Class Paths are stored in a `String array[]` where the index correlates to one of a number of MyClass's, (MyClass0, MyClass1 ... MyClass-nth).

Each MyClass has the same Methods and Data Structures, but with different values.

```
package forName;

public class Main {

    private static String toMyClassOf_ID[];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        toMyClassOf_ID = new String[1]; //new String[n];
        toMyClassOf_ID[0] = ("/exampleForName/src/forName/MyClass0.java"); //toClass[ MyClass_ID ]
    /*  .
     *  .
     *  toClass[n] = ...
     */ 
        Class toMyClass;

        try {
            Class cls = Class.forName(toMyClassOf_ID[0]);
            ClassLoader clsLoader = cls.getClassLoader();
            toMyClass= Class.forName(toMyClassOf_ID[0], true, clsLoader);
        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //toMyClass.doMethod(); //commeted to allow run test
    }
}
```

//----------

```
package forName;

public class MyClass0 {

    public static void doMethod() {
        System.out.println("success");
    }
}
```

PROBLEM:

- I am getting `"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException"`

QUESTION:

- Is `forName()` the correct approach?
- Do I have the Fully Qualified Class Path correct, `toMyClassOf_ID[0]`, for this to work? eg(`"/exampleForName/src/forName/MyClass0.java"`)
- if NOT what is the correct format to use, and how do I find it?

Comment: Try using "." as separator rather than "/".

Comment: `Class.forName()` is applicable for *class* file, not the *source* file

Comment: `/exampleForName/src/forName/MyClass0.java` is a source file.  It has to be compiled first and loaded into a `Classloader` before it can be loaded.  You would then need to use `forname.MyClass0` to the call in `Class.forName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was already stated

```
Class.forName()
```

accepts the fully qualified name of the class which is the name of the package as given in the package declaration, in your case "forName", followed by a dot followed by the name of the class as given in the class declaration, in your case "MyClass0".
So the working example would be

```
Class<?> cls = Class.forName("forName.MyClass0");
```

You can not use the path to the source file as you tried to do.

But when reading

> Each MyClass has the same Methods and Data Structures, but with different values.

I'm not sure if that is really what you should or want to do.

It sounds like you better have one class "MyClass" with instance methods and instance fields and a list of predefined instances.

You can statically initialize those instances if that is what you want to do:

```
public MyClass {
  public static final MyClass[] instances;
  static {
    instances = new MyClass[1];
    instances[0] = new MyClass();
    instances[0].myField = "value1";
  }

  private String myField;
  public void doMethod()
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Of course you could use other mechanisms to create these instances, like factory methods or dependency injection.

You said each MyClass has different values. If you also need that each MyClass has different implementations of doMethod (or any other method), you should use MyClass as base class and implement sub classes which extend from MyClass.

```
public class MyClass0 extends MyClass
{
  @Override
  public void doMethod()
  {
    // different implementation
  }
}
```

Again you can use static initialization:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public static final MyClass[] instances;
  static {
    instances = new MyClass[1];
    instances[0] = new MyClass0();
    instances[0].myField = "value1";
  }
  ...
}
```

Of course now you have dependencies from the base class to the sub classes which is generally not a good idea but I think it is a straight forward solution for your problem.

Comment: Ow, Thanks, tihs looks like it will work for what i am doing. I am new to java so what I missed might seem elementary to some. Currently I have the Classes and Methods in the source code, but having the program creating the Classes and putting values there sounds more conventional.

Comment: "If you also need that each MyClass has different implementations of doMethod" this i do not the Methods are basically just get.. calls for the Class data

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments and help. I'm not sure which is the best solution as this answer, and the answers saying to make the String "forName.MyClass0" also worked. I guess that the way I attempted first is more of a C++ style, as the Strings were like a header file. The first way - I did have to jig it up a bit with the method calls to match the forName(). But again both were successful.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the horrible naming etc, this is wrong:

```
"/exampleForName/src/forName/MyClass0.java"
```

You need:

```
"forName.MyClass0"
```

Answer (score 0):

`Class.forName` is not waiting for the path of the file, but for the full class name instead (i.e. package + class name without the .java extension): `forName.MyClass0`.

Answer (score 0):

Not the right was of specifying path to .java file

You should have .class file of your java file to use Class.forName

Refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to pass the FQCN(Fully Qualified Class Name) instead as a parameter to [forName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) instead, you are specifying the path of your .java file which is not correct.

Change the following line

```
toMyClassOf_ID[0] = ("/exampleForName/src/forName/MyClass0.java");
```

Has to be changed to -

```
toMyClassOf_ID[0] = "forName.MyClass0"; //Fully Qualified Class Name in java package notation
```